# AdaGrad denominator exponents comparison

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

**Adagrad** adapts the learning rate $ \alpha $ all along the gradient descent process, by dividing each weight on a quantity based on the sum of the previous squared gradient up to time $ t $. Therefore, the update will be large for infrequent data samples, and small for frequent ones, which makes it a perfectly suited algorithm for sparse data.

$$
\boxed{W^{(i+1)}=W^{(i)}-\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{G_{i}+\varepsilon}} \odot \nabla_{W} L\left(W^{(i)}\right)}
$$

$ \underline{where:} $

- $ G_{i} $ is diagonal matrix of size $ \mathbb{R}^{F+1,F+1} $ containing in each diagonal the sum of the squared gradient of parameter $ w_{i} $, up until time t.
- $ \varepsilon $ is a parameter that we add to avoid division by zero, usually fixed to $ 10^{-8} $.
- $ \odot $ is the element-wise product of matrices.

I have seen in a lot of places that without the square root operation, the algorithm performs much worse, such as https://www.ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/.

So I tried to set up a small experiment with the exponent of the denominator of the learning rate as a hyperparameter. The problem setup is house price prediction, and I am performing stochastic gradient descent with AdaGrad on the California Housing Dataset. Here is what I got.
[image: plot]

Now the square root, i.e. 0.5 performs pretty well, but there is no predictable pattern for the others. Has anyone analyzed why the square-root is important, and what advantages it has? 0.8 exponent has a better convergence as it achieves optimum value from the start itself.

Answer (score 0):

The 0.8 exponent fits well on your dataset, but it may not fit as well as here on other datasets. Instead, 0.5 is a standard value that ensures an average good convergence.

Comment: Yeah that's what my question is. Is the 0.5 value purely empirical or have there been theoretical convergence analysis done on it?

Comment: From the paper that introduces the adagrad algorithm ([link](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume12/duchi11a/duchi11a.pdf)) it seems that 0.5 is purely empirical. However, I read it pretty fast, so maybe I could have missed some passage that shows the convergence analysis

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).